# $ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has solution iff $p \mid b^2-4ac$ or $b^2-4ac$ is a quadratic residue $\mod p$

Tags: number-theory

Let a prime $p>2$ such that $p\nmid a$.Prove that the equation:
$$ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0 \pmod p$$
has a solution iff $p \mid b^2-4ac$ or $b^2-4ac$ is a quadratic residue $\mod p$.

Solve : $x^2+7x+10 \equiv 0 \pmod {11}$

Prove that $6x^2+5x+1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ has a solution for each prime $p$.

Can I just take the discriminant $D=b^2-4ac$??

So  the equation $ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0 \pmod p$ would have a solution,if $D \geq 0$.

If $D \equiv 0 \pmod p \Rightarrow p \mid D \Rightarrow p \mid b^2-ac$

Is it right so far? And how can I continue?

Comment: **Hint** $\ $ Do as usual, **complete the square** by multiplying by the unit $\,4a.\ \ $

Comment: Modulo $p$ integers are a field, so almost everything you know from high-school algebra applies

Answer (score 4):

Consider $ax^2+bx+c \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and multiply by $4a$, this wont change things since $p\not \mid a$, 
$$4a^2x^2+4abx+4ac=(2ax+b)^2 -(b^2-4ac)$$
So we see that the original congruence has a solution iff the congruence
$$(2ax+b)^2 \equiv b^2-4ac\pmod p$$ holds in which case $b^2-4ac$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$.

Comment: Nice,I understand..To show that $p \mid b^2-4ac$,is the way that I wrote it in my first post right??

Answer (score 2):

What you've written is correct. But you're overcomplicating!! Just factorise the quadratics - e.g. $x^2 + 7x + 10 = (x+2)(x+5)$

Indeed in these cases, the discriminants are 9 and 1, so will be quadratic residues for every $p$.

Comment: Nice observation