# Prove that $b^2-4ac \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$

Tags: number-theory

> Let $a,b,c,r$ be integers and $p \geq 5$ be a prime such that $ax^2+bx+c \equiv a(x-r)^2 \pmod{p}$. Prove that $b^2-4ac \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$. Does the same hold if $p = 3$?

I wasn't sure how to go about proving this. We can rearrange the congruence to get $$x(b+2ar)+c-ar^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}.$$ How do we continue from here?

Comment: This is hilarious. Math is hard. :P

Comment: Switching to the substance of the Question, here the identity is to hold for *all* $x$, not just a particular one.  So you can continue by assigning $x$ some felicitous values.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate, but perhaps this might give some ideas: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/844081/ax2bxc-equiv-0-pmod-p-has-solution-iff-p-mid-b2-4ac-or-b2-4ac-is-a?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Here we need to assume we have a polynomial identity mod $p$, not just an incidental equality:

$$ x(b+2ar)+c-ar^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} $$

Letting $x = 0$ gives $c - ar^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} $, so in fact $c \equiv ar^2 \pmod{p} $.

Now let $x = b - 2ar$, and use the given relation $c \equiv ar^2 \pmod{p} $:

$$ (b - 2ar)(b + 2ar) \equiv 0 \pmod{p} $$

$$ b^2 - 4a^2r^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} $$

Finally backsubstituting $c \equiv ar^2 \pmod{p} $ gives the desired result:

$$ b^2 - 4ac \equiv 0 \pmod{p} $$

In this direction no restriction on $p$ is necessary to get the implication.

Answer (score 0):

Since $ax^2+bx+c \equiv a(x-r)^2 \pmod{p}$ is a "forall" statement for all the x in least residue system  with respect to p,

$x(b+2ar)+c-ar^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$  also satisfies this condition.

Since $0$ and $1$ are in the  least residue system  with respect to p, Therefore

$$0 \times (b+2ar)+c-ar^2 \equiv c-ar^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \tag{1}$$

$$1 \times (b+2ar)+c-ar^2 \equiv (b+2ar) \equiv 0 \pmod{p} \tag{2}$$

Then from $(1)$ and $(2)$, $b^2 - 4ac \equiv (-2ar)^2 - 4a(ar^2) \equiv 4a^2r^2- 4a^2r^2 \equiv 0 \pmod{p}$